# Work done by friction on a ball flying through air

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, friction, work

> A baseball of mass 145 g leaves a pitcher’s hand at 150km/hr, but due to constant air resistance, it arrives at home plate 20.0m away traveling at 145km/hr Assume that the magnitude of the ball’s acceleration is constant and that the ball travels in a straight line (ignore gravity). How much work is done by friction during the ﬂight of the ball? What is the magnitude of the force of air resistance? 3

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Related question by OP 5 minutes earlier: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/195126/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be your assignment, problem set or so:

So instead I will not be spoon feeding you much, here is the method:

Use this formula:

**Work** = **F**x**D** = **KE**f - **KE**i

where:

```
      KE - Kinetic energy

      F  - Friction

      D  - Distance
```

Remember: **KE** = **m**x**v**/2

Note: Convert units to SI

Comment: Questions where are just transcriptions of homework-type problems should not be answered. They are against the rules of this site. Answering them encourages more of them.